# How to do - QToolButton inside the QlineEdit : Qt5

Tags: windows, qt5, qlineedit, qpushbutton

I want to add `QToolButton` inside the `QLineEdit`.

I want to clear the text of `QLineEdit` control on that button click.

For example how in google image:

[image]

I have looked :

This [`StackOverflow article`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462562/how-to-do-inside-in-qlineedit-insert-the-button-pyqt4)

But still not solved my issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//Create QToolButton:

```
QToolButton *clearButton = new QToolButton(this);
QPixmap pixmap(":/new/AppResource/images/clear_button.png");
clearButton->setIcon(QIcon(pixmap));
clearButton->setIconSize(pixmap.size());
clearButton->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
clearButton->setStyleSheet("QToolButton { border: none; padding: 0px; }");
clearButton->hide();
```

Connect Signal-Slot:

```
connect(clearButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(clear()));
connect(this, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(updateCloseButton(const QString&)));
```

Visible on Text Enter into serach box:

```
clearButton->setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Yes, I do not think I have found a way to put a QToolButton inside the QLineEdit. It is like that they better go together in a horizontal layout.

Answer (score 13):

This behaviour is available as a direct property to QLineEdit since Qt ***5.2***:

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlineedit.html#clearButtonEnabled-prop

```
QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(this);
edit->setClearButtonEnabled(true);
```

You can add a custom QAction with your self-defined icons to the QLineEdit:

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlineedit.html#addAction

```
QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(this);
QAction *action =
    edit->addAction(QIcon("/path/to/icon"), QLineEdit::ActionPosition::LeadingPosition);
connect(action, &QAction::triggered, this, &ThisObject::doSomething);
```

Comment: For python users it works like this: `action = edit.addAction(QIcon('icon.png'), QLineEdit::ActionPosition::TrailingPosition)` Then do `action.triggered.connect(func_name)`

Comment: This is, however, not what the OP is asking for. He is asking for a QToolButton inside a QLineEdit, which makes sense. Sometimes, you may want to have a drop-down list (menu) that QToolButton offers instead of a raw icon. The clear is a slightly special case here.