# Adding QToolButton inside QlineEdit

Tags: python, button, qt4, qt-designer, qlineedit

I am trying to implement a qToolButton onto the qLineEdit. Basically this toolButton serves something like a file browser.

I did found a few links but I am simply not getting it, for example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102558/how-to-do-qtoolbutton-inside-the-qlineedit-qt5)
as I am doing out my UI using the Qt Designer.

I tried using the solution within the link as a guide but I am unable to find such parameters within the software.

As such, was wondering if this can be doable in Qt Designer?

Comment: Which Qt Version are you using?

Comment: @Mailerdaimon I am using 4.6.2

Comment: Is it possible with the current Qt version that I am using?

Comment: Possible yes, but i don´t know how to do it using the designer or if this is even possible. If you code your widget that is no problem at all. With Qt 5.3 (i think) this is supported by QLineEdit without the need for code changes.

Comment: I see, thought it may be easy to code despite I am using Qt4, guess not :p I will try searching online for more information then. Thanks, @Mailerdaimon