# Does PySide.QtGui.QWidget.addAction( ) can take position argument?

Tags: python, pyside

Can or can't i use `PySide.QtGui.QWidget.addAction` to place a icon in front of the lineEdit even if this method can take onle one argument in Pyside1?

I want to implement a login UI in my `python` scripts for 3ds Max, just like [How to place an icon onto a QLineEdit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958381/how-to-place-an-icon-onto-a-qlineedit)
, but i **have to use PySide1** because **3ds Max only supports PySide1 before version-2018**.

I check Pyside1 and Pyside2 API and i find that:

> In PySide1, the method `PySide.QtGui.QWidget.addAction(action)`can only take 1 arg. [this is pyside1 api](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.addAction)
>
> But in Pyside2, the same method takes one more arg, like:`PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.addAction(icon, position)`, which is what i want because i need to place an icon in fornt of the `QLineEdit`.[this is pyside2 api](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QLineEdit.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.addAction)

this is my partly code, `self.usernameStr` in my `class`, no error.

```py
# pyside1, which is wrong to take 2 args
# it's in my class
self.usernameStr = QtGui.QLineEdit()
self.usernameStr.addAction("ic_user.svg", QLineEdit().LeadingPosition)
```

which is wrong, `TypeError: addAction() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

But in pyside2, `addAction` can take the constant `LeadingPosition`, perfectly like the answer. [stackoverflow: how-to-place-an-icon-onto-a-qlineedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958381/how-to-place-an-icon-onto-a-qlineedit)

So can or can't i implement this function? Thanks very much for your answer :)

Comment: Sure, you can implement it: just take a look at the [qt5 source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit_p.cpp.html#523) and backport all the relevant code to pyside - it should only take a few hours (-; Or if that doesn't appeal to you, why not create a simple custom widget which contains a tool-button and a frameless line-edit (which should only take you twenty minutes or so).